# CVRP where customers can be visited more than once

Tags: python, optimization, vehicle-routing

I want to resolve a problem that looks like a vehicle routing problem with capacity (CVRP), but where customers can be visited more than once so that their demand can be fulfilled.

I have:

- a complete graph G(V,A) with suppliers and a deposit
- a cost_matrix M
- 4 vehicles with a capacity Q
- A positive function f on V that indicates the quantity that has to be supplied for each customer.

My goal is to supply all the customers with the 4 vehicles. Customers can be visited by two vehicles.

The total routing distance has to be minimized.

I want to solve this problem with python.

I've have consulted some documentation (flow-problems, TSP, VRP, CVRP bin packing...). But unsuccessfully.

Do you know if this problem has a name ? If it is documented? Otherwise, how should-I formulate the problem?
Which Python library should-I use?

Thank you !

Comment: is this not just a variation of traveling sales man? afaik this problem space is np-hard and requires complete exploration, any short cuts could lead to non-optimal solutions ...

It would also be good to show your inputs (a simplified version maybe) and your expected output ... as well as whatever progress you have made on the problem

Comment: I am not sure what the proper name for it is, probably something like vrp with multiple visits. Contrary to what @JoranBeasley says, the solution doesn't require complete exploration as it is indeed np-hard and infeasible to enumerate all solutions. I have modelled a similar problem using Optaplanner before, a way to implement it could be to treat each stop's demand as a discrete number (e.g. 1). That way that single demand can be assigned to any vehicle. If this creates an explosion in the planning variables, you can think of smarter ways to aggregate them together. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Joran and k88. For the while, as I did not find satisfying articles, I wrote my own optimization problem using the library docplex.mp.model. It looks like a flow problem (I will soon write it here). I can afford a Branch and Bonds resolution because my instances are pretty little (5 suppliers and 5 vehicles). Still, I will read articles about VRP with multiple visits as suggested. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Split delivery Vehicle Routing Problem (SDVRP).

It's a variation of the classic VRP where a customer could be visited more than once.
The problem can be formulated as integer linear programming(ILP) but it's still an np-hard.

For further details, you can refer to https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X9200172I.

Hope this helps.